# How to parameterize this surface: $x_{3}^{2}+x_{4}^{2}=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}$ s.t. $0<x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}<R^{2}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

The following equation represents a surface in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, that
is a 3-dimensional manifold:
$$
x_{3}^{2}+x_{4}^{2}=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}\qquad\text{s.t.}\qquad 0<x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}<R^{2}
$$
We can see that by defining $F\colon\mathbb{R}^{4}\to\mathbb{R}$
to be $$F\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}\right)=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}-x_{3}^{2}-x_{4}^{2}$$
so that $\nabla F\left(x\right)=2\left(x_{1},x_{2},-x_{3},-x_{4}\right)\neq0$,
and the manifold is $M=F^{-1}\left(0\right)$.

My question is how can we parameterize this surface? I'm looking for
a $V\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and a function $r\colon V\to\mathbb{R}^{4}$
such that $M=r\left(V\right)$. That is in order to compute the surface
area of $M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0<x_1^2+x_2^2 < R^2$

$x_1,x_2$ lie on a disk.

$x_3^2 + x_4^2 = x_1^2+x_2^2$ puts $x_3, x_4$ on a corresponding disk.

$x_1 = \rho \cos \theta\\
x_2 = \rho \sin\theta\\
x_3 = \rho \cos \phi\\
x_4 = \rho \sin \phi$

$0<\rho < R\\
0\le \theta < 2\pi\\
0\le \phi < 2\pi$